# Vertical Alignment Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: bootstrap-4, carousel

I'm slowly getting where I want with my portfolio page. However, a little question remains. I'm having a few bootstrap carousels, that all have the following code:

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">

<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"> </li >
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"> </li>
        <li data-target ="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"> </li>
      </ol >

      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active" >
        <img class="d-block w-50" src="image1.jpg" alt="First slide">
        <div class="carousel-captionp" "position=static">
     <h1><Caption</h1>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
      <img class="d-block w-50" src="image2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="carousel-captionp">
        <h1>Caption</h1>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
      <img class="d-block w-50" src="image3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="carousel-captionp">
      <h1>Caption</h1>
      </div>
      </div>


      <a class="portrait right carousel-control" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">
      <span><img src="css/ARROW.png" width="50%" padding-top="50%"></span>
      </a>
      </div>
      </div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.carousel {
  position: relative;

}
.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 98vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.carousel-inner > .item {
  position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
       -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
          transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
}
```

My idea was that the images stay at 98vh so, the carousel never runs over the window height. Making the window bigger this results in a crop of the image on bottom, while scaling with the page its width. What I wanted to ask, is if someone knows how to make this crop on top and bottom, so the picture remains aligned in the middle? vertical-align in the CSS somehow didn't solve the problem...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you add your code (e.g., JSFiddle)?

Comment: I pasted the code, JSFiddle didn't work. I'm quite new to this, so please excuse my inability...